# In Salesforce Post Chat getting refused to connect error

Tags: liveagent, survey, salesforce-survey

I followed the steps suggested under: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69878970/in-salesforce-post-chat-getting-refused-to-connect-error/77322529#77322529, but am still not able to move past this error.

**Setup:**

- I have a chat setup where I want to display the survey. For this I
  created a Survey & linked to the Embedded Service Deployment.
- Associated a default Community site, so I can generate the Survey link for option 'Participants Outside Your Company'.
- Copied the Survey link (Participants Outside Your Company) to the Chat button Post-Chat URL.
- We have an external site in live environment for chat (& thus for this survey in future), but I'm using VF to test my setup in my lower sandbox. So I
  allowlisted the VF URL under Trusted Domains with IFrame Type as
  'Surveys'.

**I also tried following things but it did not work:**

- Under Clickjack Protection checked 'Enable clickjack protection for customer Visualforce pages with standard headers' & 'Enable clickjack protection for customer Visualforce pages with headers disabled'.
- For default Community site associated with Surveys, checked 'Guest users can see and interact with the site without logging in' for Public Access
- Provided access to Survey Invitations obj for Guest User Profile for the default Community site -- although only Read access was available.
- Allowlisted default Community site's URL also under Trusted Domains with IFrame Type as 'Surveys'.

Any suggestions?